# Are prions an important driver in evolution?

Tags: epigenetics

I understand that prions have been implicated in the passing on of epigentic information<sup>[[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2009.02.044)]</sup>. Are prions thought to play a significant role in the evolution of organisms?

1. [**Alberti S, Halfmann R, King O, Kapila A, Lindquist S**. 2009. A systematic survey identifies prions and illuminates sequence features of prionogenic proteins. Cell 137: 146–58.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cell.2009.02.044)

Comment: @aland Thanks for your effort to improve the quality of citations in the questions and answers on this site. You may be interested in [this thread](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/337/43) in the meta regarding the best location for complete/verbose references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is proposed that prions are a good mechanism for "testing" phenotypic variation.

There are many identified proteins with prion-determining domains (PrD) in the yeast genome that can spontaneously switch between conformations with some low probability (eg: check [SUP35](http://www.yeastgenome.org/cgi-bin/locus.fpl?dbid=S000002579) for one example, and [1] for a good overview of more). The theory is that:

1. the low probability of switching from non-prion to prion state allows for many more mutations and variations to accumulate -- generating greater genetic diversity than in standard expressed gene variability where most mutations are silent or detrimental
2. the prions provide a ready form of non-permanent inheritability that can be "trialed" by offspring and others in a colony of organisms -- this can be especially beneficial during say temporary changes in environment
3. if the prion phenotype is widely successful, selective pressure can easily mutate it into a more permanent fixture in the genome.

Check out the excellent paper published just last week in Nature exploring this this topic [2]. To give a sense of just how evolutionarily-advantageous prions can be, in the author's experiments and analysis they note that 40% of the prion traits they analyzed were beneficial to growth (eg:  in the paper strain UCD939 gains additional resistance to acidic conditions from the prion [PSI+]).

Assuming these hypothesis, prions would thus play a significant role in the evolution and variability of organisms.

[1] [Crow, et. al. 2011. doi:10.1016/j.semcdb.2011.03.003](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1084952111000413)

[2] [Halfmann, et. al. 2012. doi:10.1038/nature10875](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v482/n7385/full/nature10875.html)